# Spring-retrial internal implementation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

I was going through spring-retry framework tutorial : https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-use-spring-retry

But I wanted to know how it works internally. I want to use it for one of my API calls but before doing that wanted to know few things about the internal implementation which I had no luck finding out.

1. Does spring-retry saves the message in some messaging queue before retrying it after sometime?
2. Does it save it in some object in memory.
3. Does it use the same thread pool or a different one is used?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it simply inserts an interceptor between the caller and called code.
2. No; the arguments to the method call are simply stack variables.
3. The called code is called directly on the calling thread - it is just an interceptor.